# Test and set a bit atomically using inline aarch64 assembly

Tags: assembly, atomic, arm

The code below has been a vehicle for learning the syntax of inline assembly for gcc/clang and that is the focus of my question.  In addition to anything else that I've missed I would also like feedback on the following statements:

- If `r`'s constraint were instead `"=r"` then the compiler would be free to assume that the asm *will* write its value and, therefore, to drop the apparently redundant statement `int r = 1`.  Marking `r` read-write tells the compiler that the asm relies on its previous value and therefore forces the previously calculated value to remain available.
- The dummy output `"=m" (*addr)` tells the compiler that the 32-bit word stored at `addr` is an output of the asm and that, where this word appears in the asm, it should be represented by memory.  A) directing memory to be represented by memory is redundant and B) the expression is unused in the asm;  therefore the dummy output has no effect on the asm generated.  It does, however, advertise to the compiler that the asm has a side effect of modifying a word of memory at `addr`.  Adding `"memory"` to the clobber list is therefore unnecessary.
- By default, the compiler assumes that output operands are written after input operands have been consumed and, therefore, that the same register could be used for both an input *and* an output.  For example, `tmp` might be assigned `x0`.  Specifying `"=&r" (tmp)` avoids this by forcing the provision of a register unused by anything listed as an input (but I do not understand whether there remains a risk of collision with other outputs also constrained by `"=&r"`).

```
#include <inttypes.h>

/*
 * Set the nth bit atomically in the word at addr where n < 32.  Return 1 if
 * the bit was already set and 0 otherwise.
 */
int
asb(uint32_t *addr, int n)
{
    uint32_t tmp;
    uint32_t stat;
    int r = 1;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "1:\n\t"
        "ldaxr  %w[tmp], [%[addr]]\n\t"
        "tst    %w[tmp], %w[bit]\n\t"
        "bne    2f\n\t"
        "orr    %w[tmp], %w[tmp], %w[bit]\n\t"
        "stlxr  %w[stat], %w[tmp], [%[addr]]\n\t"
        "cbnz   %w[stat], 1b\n\t"
        "mov    %w[r], #0\n\t"
        "2:\n\t"
        "clrex\n\t"
        : [tmp] "=&r" (tmp), [stat] "=&r" (stat), [r] "+r" (r), "=m" (*addr)
        : [addr] "r" (addr), [bit] "r" (1 << n)
        : "cc"
    );

    return (r);
}
```